# Is it actually bad practice to ignore non-static resources using WebSecurity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Let's say in my Spring Security configuration i would like to allow all `OPTIONS` requests.

To me the simplest way to do this would be the following:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
}
```

But the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.10.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html#ignoring--) of `WebSecurity.ignoring()` says the following:

> Typically the requests that are registered should be that of only
>   static resources.
>
> For requests that are dynamic, consider mapping the
>   request to allow all users instead.

So according to this recommendation i would use `HttpSecurity` instead:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll();
}
```

Which is more code by itself, but let's say i would like to add a JWT filter as well:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
           .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/some_endpoint_that_needs_the_filter").authenticated();
}
```

If i do it like this, the `Filter` will be applied to the `OPTIONS` requests as well, which is not what i want. Of course i can prevent it, but that would be even more code to add to achieve the same thing basically.

Are there any actual downsides of using `WebSecurity.ignoring()` in this (or any other) case?

Why is it not recommended to ignore non-static resources with `WebSecurity`?